# Eclipse only allows exporting .cpp to .xml

Tags: c++, xml, eclipse

Eclipse only gives me the option to export my .cpp file to XML. As I would like to create a finished piece, and I am using a mac, barring .exe, this is quite frustrating. Any help that could be provided would be most appreciated.

Comment: Exporting .cpp to xml? What the content of the xml should be? May be you mean exporting to html?

Comment: Eclipse specifically states it as XML.

Comment: Please show example xml, if you want to export .cpp to html with syntax highlighting, there are many other instruments to do so.

Comment: What I would like to do is export .cpp to an executable file of any kind that works on a mac, so no .exe. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: If you want to compile cpp to mac executable, you should say it in your question like so; but i think you should create an eclipse project(if you haven't already), add the cpp file to sources and click build button.